# Create polygon from CCSprite?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

Is there a way to create a polygon from a ccsprite? Such that I can then call

```
CCPhysicsBody(polygonFromPoints: <#UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>#>, count: <#UInt#>, cornerRadius: <#CGFloat#>)
```

on said points?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried or taken a look at the [Physics Editor](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor)? You can use it to create your physics polygons using a visual tool. I used it quite a bit with cocos2d apps in the past.